# How to find links within a specified class with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm using Beautiful Soup 4 to parse a news site for links contained in the body text. I was able to find all the paragraphs that contained the links but the `paragraph.get('href')` returned type `none` for each link.  I'm using Python 3.5.1. Any help is really appreciated.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import re

soup = BeautifulSoup("http://www.cnn.com/2016/11/18/opinions/how-do-you-deal-with-donald-trump-dantonio/index.html", "html.parser")

for paragraph in soup.find_all("div", class_="zn-body__paragraph"):
    print(paragraph.get('href'))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you really want this?

```
for paragraph in soup.find_all("div", class_="zn-body__paragraph"):
    for a in paragraph("a"):
       print(a.get('href'))
```

Note that `paragraph.get('href')` tries to find *attribute* `href` in `<div>` tag you found. As there's no such attribute, it returns `None`. Most probably you actually have to find all tags `<a>` which a descendants of your `<div>` (this can be done with `paragraph("a")` which is a shortcut for `paragraph.find_all("a")` and then for every element `<a>` look at their `href` attribute.